# Stock exchange robbery in The Dark Knight Rises

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

I have seen *The Dark Knight Rises* quite a few times and I am unable to understand the significance of Bane raiding the stock exchange. Miranda Tate is already known to be a billionaire so why does Bane need any more money? 
The relevance is not explained in the movie after the scene. Was it just set up to set a grand entrance for Bruce?

The program was anyway running through wireless medium, why didn't they just rob the exchange remotely?  Neither did Bane know Batman is to return, the cops would've chased them to the tunnels and the show would've been over before it began.

Comment: Duplicate with a few more points added i think :D @AnkitSharma